# How to apply new changes back to html using click(this) event?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to return or apply new changes back to html when clicking on it.

Take a look at the "TODO" comment.  I can see new value changes on $(o1) but how to bubble it up to the on-click caller having "this" value?

```
var fooMouseClick = function(parmThis)
{
    var $HtmlSpans = $(parmThis.parentElement.innerHtml);

    $.each($HtmlSpans, function(i1, o1) {
        if ($(o1).attr('data-column-sort-ordering') == "") {
           $(o1).attr('data-column-sort-ordering', 'ASC');

           //TODO - How to apply this new "$(o1)" changes to parmThis so the parent script caller can be updated.
        }
    });
}
var foo2 = function() 
{
    $('#Box1 li[title="Model"] span.SpanRight-SortOrdering').click(function() {
        fooMouseClick(this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `$(parmThis.parentElement.innerHtml);` creates ***a new object***, so every change you make will not change the original one.

Try this:

```
var fooMouseClick = function(parmThis)
{
    var $HtmlSpans = $(parmThis).parent().children();

    $.each($HtmlSpans, function(i1, o1) {
        if ($(o1).attr('data-column-sort-ordering') == "") {
           $(o1).attr('data-column-sort-ordering', 'ASC');

        }
    });
}
```

Also notice that if your selector is based on your dynamically changed values, you should use delegated event handler. For example, use this code if you want to handle click event of elements having `data-column-sort-ordering="ASC"` (this value is changed dynamically):

```
$('#Box1').on("click",'li[title="Model"] span[data-column-sort-ordering="ASC"]',function() {
        fooMouseClick(this);
});
```

Comment: One thing you need to know.  delegate is depreciated in later JQuery version.

Comment: @fletchsod: using `.delegated()` to attach delegated event handlers is deprecated and should use `.on()`. `Delegated event handlers` are still in use in jquery and are not deprecated. Please check that the answer uses `.on()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Box1").on("click","li[title='Model'] span.SpanRight-SortOrdering",function() {
    fooMouseClick(this);
});
```

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything.  The click event did fire though.